# Facebook Test User and iOS6 OS Integration

Tags: ios6, facebook-test-users

I'd like to use my FaceBook test users (which can be used in a browser and username/password are working correctly) in my iPhone Simulator and iPhone itself for trying to post from an application. If I try to register the FaceBook test account in iOS6 Settings, I got an error

> Could not communicate with the server

This error is different from username/password wrong and seems to work for almost 30 seconds before the error pops up. (The login via Mobile Safari works flawless)

Any ideas what I should try to get iOS6 to work with my FaceBook test user?

Best regards
A.Steinel

Comment: Are you sure your app is properly connected to the web? Did you try to connect to the facebook server using a `NSURLConnection`? Sharing some of the code you're using might help answer the question.

Comment: @leo: I use the Settings App from Apple. The test user is not working there (iOS 6 Facebook Connect by Apple).

Comment: There are other reports about this problem, yet there is no real solution for test users, because they are not open other apps like the Apple Settings App (as I understand it).

https://discussions.apple.com/message/19625167#19625167
https://discussions.apple.com/message/19663887#19663887
http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/iphone-hardware-accessories/284951-iphone-4-ios-6-facebook-integration.html